# How to list the slots for a web app using the "scm.azurewebsites.net" url

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have trigger jobs and want to stop and start them using PowerShell. Is there a way to get a list of slots for web app from the `scm.azurewebsites.net`?

It is easier to use the creds from the publish profile rather than having users login to Azure and use the PowerShell Azure Functions.

Comment: Is your question more "how to call the Azure API from scm site" (regardless of specific call), or "how to get the list of slots from the ARM API" (regardless of where you make the call from)? The question as state seems to conflate the two, which are mostly unrelated.

Comment: I'd prefer to be able to get the list of slots from scm REST interface if there is a way. Using the creds from the publish profile is great. I was working top avoid having the user at the console login to Azure, as well as avoid using a service principal.

Comment: There is no way to do this just from scm site and publishing creds (which are site level). Only the ARM API lets you do that. You may want to look at [managed service identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity) (in Preview)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the link.